# Writing containers that can handle implicit sharing, but turn it off for non-copyable types (like unique_ptr)?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, containers, unique-ptr

I dug up an old `Grid` class, which is just a simple 2-D container templated with a type.  To make one you would do this:

```
Grid<SomeType> myGrid (QSize (width, height));
```

I tried to make it "Qt-ish"...for instance it does size operations in terms of `QSize`, and you index into it with `myGrid[QPoint (x, y)]`.  It can take boolean masks and do operations on elements whose mask bit was set.  There's also a specialization where if your elements are `QColor` it can generate a `QImage` for you.

But one major Qt idiom I adopted was that it did [implicit sharing](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/implicit-sharing.html) under the hood.  This turned out to be very useful in the QColor-based grids for the [Thinker-Qt](http://hostilefork.com/thinker-qt/)-based program I had.

**However** :-/ I also happened to have some cases where I'd written the likes of:

```
Grid< auto_ptr<SomeType> > myAutoPtrGrid (QSize (width, height));
```

When I moved up from `auto_ptr` to C++11's `unique_ptr`, the compiler rightfully complained.  Implicit sharing requires the ability to make an identical copy if needed...and `auto_ptr` had swept this bug under the rug by conflating copying with transfer-of-ownership.  Non-copyable types and implicit sharing simply do not mix, and `unique_ptr` is kind enough to tell us.

*(Note: It so happened that I hadn't noticed the problem in practice, because the use cases for the `auto_ptr` were passing grids by reference...never by value.  Still, this was bad code...and the proactive nature of C++11 is pointing out the potential problem before it happens.)*

Ok, so...how might I design a generic container that can flip implicit sharing on and off?  I really did want many of the Grid features when I was using the `auto_ptr` and it's great if copying is disabled for non-copyable types...that catches errors!  But having the implicit sharing work is nice as a default, when the type happens to be copyable.

Some ideas:

- I could make separate types (`NonCopyableGrid`, `CopyableGrid`)...or (`UniqueGrid`, `Grid`) depending on your tastes...
- I could pass a flag into the `Grid` constructor
- I could use static factory methods (`Grid::newNonCopyable`, `Grid::newCopyable`) but which would call the relevant constructor under the hood...maybe more descriptive
- If possible, I might "detect" copyability on the contained type, and then either leverage a [QSharedDataPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshareddatapointer.html) in the implementation or not, depending?

Any good reasons to pick one of these methods over the others, or have people adopted something altogether better for this kind of situation?

Comment: @LucDanton The container doesn't functionally require anything but move...it's just this glitch caused by the implicit sharing mechanism itself. (Implicit sharing is just a name for passing things around "by value", but under the hood they're passed by pointer...w/a copy-on-write when they get tainted by non-const access to their data.  Easiest understood by reading the Qt doc for [QSharedDataPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshareddatapointer.html#details)) My question is how to have a single container that can do this but flips to only passable by move or reference for noncopyables.

Comment: @LucDanton "The glitch" is simply that implicit sharing hinges on a "copy-on-write" pattern, therefore the type must be able to be copied when written, Q.E.D.  :)  Again...the issue is not the container's functionality, just trying to use this prevalent pattern in Qt *most* of the time, but disable it if the type is non-copyable. I don't know enough about the practices regarding this, C++11 is very new after all. Just checking to see if anyone has hit this...maybe there is a way to use type traits? I want implicit sharing if copyable, and only pass-by-reference-or-move if not, that's all...

Comment: The -1 is because I find that the question is a little bit too similar to open-ended 'design' questions which I consider to not always fit the Q&A format. I find it very suspect for instance that there is very little code. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610087/advice-needed-to-choose-design-patterns-for-a-multithreaded-application)'s an example of a question that shares some warts with yours: vague considerations about code that isn't shown and a list of possible options. Both OPs also do not relate what obstacles, if any, prevent them from making a choice themselves.

Comment: @LucDanton Despite yours and my comments disappearing as per 1984, I will reiterate that I feel this question is clear, answerable, and in fact has an answer that (with slight modifications) works like a charm.  See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were going to do it in a single container, I think the easiest way would be to use `std::is_copy_constructable` to choose whether your data struct inherited from `QSharedData`, and to replace `QSharedDataPointer` with `std::unique_ptr` *(`QScopedPointer` doesn't support move semantics)*

This is only a rough example of what I'm thinking as I don't have Qt and C++11 available together:

```
template<class T>
class Grid
{       
    struct EmptyStruct
    {
    };

    typedef typename std::conditional<
        std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value,  
        QSharedData,  
        EmptyStruct
    >::type GridDataBase;

    struct GridData : public GridDataBase
    {
        // data goes here
    };

    typedef typename std::conditional<
        std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value, 
        QSharedDataPointer<GridData>, 
        std::unique_ptr<GridData>
    >::type GridDataPointer;

public:
    Grid() : data_(new GridData) {}

private:
    GridDataPointer data_;
};
```

Comment: Like I said, my knowledge isn't up to date, so I didn't know `std::is_copy_constructible` was on the table.  I'd consider it.  You're right to say that the performance characteristics change, but it seems this is either COPYABLE or NOT...and the copyable case degenerates to what I was happy to act like a Qt class, while the non-copyable class must be handled with kid gloves so you know what you're getting. Seems enabling if anything...no worse than the original concept of implicit sharing?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Kudos, I think you nailed it for the most part. A couple of issues I've modified in your code as I do have C++11 and Qt here. :) Feel free to fix up further. Firstly QScopedPointer doesn't do move semantics (disabled by Q_DISABLE_COPY), so using unique_ptr makes it possible to write the move routines for Grid-or-whatever-the-container-is. Secondly, the is_copy_constructible check passes for GridData, and rather than fix that it's easier to just use T in both cases. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**

I don't really understand your `Grid` template or your use cases.  However I do understand containers in general.  So maybe this answer applies to your `Grid<T>` and maybe it doesn't.

Since you've already stated the intent that `Grid< unique_ptr<T> >` would indicate unique ownership and a non-copyable `T`, what about doing something similar with copy on write?

What about explicitly stating when you want to use copy on write with:

```
Grid< cow_ptr<T> >
```

A `cow_ptr<T>` would offer reference counting copies, but on a "non-const dereference" would do a copy of `T` if the refcount is not 1.  So `Grid` need not worry about memory management to such an extent.  It would need only to handle its data buffer, and perhaps move or copy its members around in `Grid`'s copy and/or move members.

A `cow_ptr<T>` is fairly easily cobbled together by wrapping `std::shared_ptr<T>`.  Here is a partial implementation I put together about a month ago when dealing with a similar issue:

```
template <class T>
class cow_ptr
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_;
public:
    template <class ...Args,
              class = typename std::enable_if
                      <
                         std::is_constructible<std::shared_ptr<T>, Args...>::value
                      >::type
             >
        explicit cow_ptr(Args&& ...args)
            : ptr_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        {}

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept {return ptr_ != nullptr;}

    T const* read() const noexcept {return ptr_.get();}
    T      * write()
    {
        if (ptr_.use_count() > 1)
            ptr_.reset(ptr_->clone());
        return ptr_.get();
    }

    T const& operator*() const noexcept {return *read();}
    T const* operator->() const noexcept {return read();}

    void reset() {ptr_.reset();}
    template <class Y>
        void
        reset(Y* p)
        {
            ptr_.reset(p);
        }
};
```

I chose to make the "write" syntax very explicit, since COW tends to be more effective when there are very few writes, but many reads/copies.  To gain const access, you use it just like any other pointer:

```
p->inspect();  // compile time error if inspect() isn't const
```

But to do some modifying operation you have to call it out with the `write` member function:

```
p.write()->modify();
```

`shared_ptr` has a bunch of really handy constructors and I didn't want to have to replicate all of them in `cow_ptr`.  So the one `cow_ptr` constructor you see is a poor man's implementation of inheriting constructors that also works for data members.

You may need to fill this out with other smart pointer functionality such as relational operators.  You may also want to change how `cow_ptr` copies a `T`.  I'm currently assuming a virtual `clone()` function but you could easily substitute into `write` the use of T's copy constructor instead.

If an explicit `Grid< cow_ptr<T> >` doesn't really fit your needs, that's all good.  I figured I'd share just in case it did.

Comment: +1 for the interesting idea of the type system to let the client to indicate copy-on-write (that didn't occur to me). Definitely belongs in the list of "what's possible", and I wouldn't be using C++ if I weren't open to the idea of using the type system for such magic. But I think what @Slavik81 suggests is the easiest generalization for anyone with a QSharedData container who wants a path of least resistance for non-copyable types. Thank you for taking the time to make a suggestion!